# Problems No route matches [POST] "/login"

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

now I need to see this error that it gives me
No route matches [POST] "/login"

the code is the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
      <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Logo_App' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <br>
      <h2 class="pb-4 text"><%= "Ingresar" %></h2>
      <%= simple_form_for :contacts, url: loginuser_path do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :mail, label: "Correo Electronico" %>
        <%= f.input :pass, label: "Contraseña" %>
        <%= f.submit "Admitir" %>
      <% end %>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello guys, now I need to see this error that it gives me
No route matches [POST] "/login"

the code is the following:

what would be a solution thanks

---

```
root to: 'pages#home'
  
  get "/login", to:"contacts#loginuser", as: :loginuser
  
  
  resources :admins
  resources :clients do
    resources :change_policies, only: %i[ index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :age_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :refund_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :reservation_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :cancel_policies, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :rooms, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :contacts, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update show destroy]    
  end

  resources :reservation, only: %i[index] do
    resources :item_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :user_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :other_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
    resources :obs_reservations, only: %i[index new create edit update destroy]
  end
 
  resources :registrations, only: %i[new create]
```

Comment: Change `get "/login",...` to `post "/login",..` although are you sure this route is designed to handle a sign in ? As it is not common and not safe to send form data with `get` request.

Comment: It is not for the session I use Devise it is only, it requires that the personnel of the companies (client) log in to keep a history only that.

Comment: When making the change I now get a GET error

Comment: Please update your question with the new error and any new details.